# Reading blocks from devices

Tags: kernel, block, device

I trying to write a fs in kernel mode, and i can not use buffers/ cache (such as in sb_bread(..)).
who do I read and write blocks directly from/to my block device.

Im writing a distributed fs (over netwrok) since not all blocks are from same device/machine.
buffers are little problematic.

thanks,
Dan

Comment: Can you clarify two things: First, what platform are you coding for? Second, when you say "distributed", do you mean the filesystem is distributed (multiple instances serve the same files)? Or the filesystem's backing store is distributed (filesystem has exclusive access to multiple backing stores)?

Comment: If you are still interested in this, take a look at the Nework Block Device module: http://nbd.sourceforge.net/